# pandas dataframe: groupby by several columns, apply function and map back the result

Tags: python, pandas

Here there is an example:

```py
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.random(size=10),
                   "y": np.arange(10)})
df["z"] = np.where(df.x < 0.5, 0, 1)
print df
```

It gives the following result:

```
          x  y  z
0  0.417022  0  0
1  0.720324  1  1
2  0.000114  2  0
3  0.302333  3  0
4  0.146756  4  0
5  0.092339  5  0
6  0.186260  6  0
7  0.345561  7  0
8  0.396767  8  0
9  0.538817  9  1
```

I want to add a new column `mean` into `df` with mean values computed for values of `x` column grouped by `y` and `z` columns. I already know how to compute mean values:

```
tmp = df.groupby(["y", "z"]).mean()
```

However I can't find out how to map back the results into a new column `mean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `transform` to add the result of your `groupby` operation back as a column, `transform` returns a `Series` with it's index aligned to the original df:

```
In [15]:
df['mean'] = df.groupby(["y", "z"]).transform('mean')
df

Out[15]:
          x  y  z      mean
0  0.423578  0  0  0.423578
1  0.270675  1  0  0.270675
2  0.707611  2  1  0.707611
3  0.589192  3  1  0.589192
4  0.768653  4  1  0.768653
5  0.420577  5  0  0.420577
6  0.930490  6  1  0.930490
7  0.380576  7  0  0.380576
8  0.055940  8  0  0.055940
9  0.678355  9  1  0.678355
```